# How do I get the parameters of a post request when using a pac4j security filter in Spark Java?

Tags: java, filter, spark-java

In my Spark app, I have a simple form whose input I send to the server using a POST request. The request is handled by evaluating its body and extracting the desired parameters:

```
post("/upload",(request, response) -> {
    String body = request.body();
    MultiMap<String> parameters = decodeParams(body);
    // post-process parameters
    // ...
    return "success";
});
```

Everything works as expected as long as I do not define a [pac4j](https://github.com/pac4j/spark-pac4j) security filter which makes sure the user of my app is logged in. This is how I set up the filter:

```
// ...
MyConfig config = new MyConfig(salt, templateEngine);

CallbackRoute callback = new CallbackRoute(config, null, true);
get("/callback", callback);
post("/callback", callback);

before("/upload", new SecurityFilter(config, "FormClient"));
```

The effect of this filtering is the body (in my first code snippet) being null.

I found [this old post in the sparkjava Google group](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/sparkjava/SwFnVmX28Zk/J_LaFtyNq4UJ) that describes the same problem including a first analysis of the root cause. Unfortunately, it's more than two years old and has not received a reply yet.

**EDIT:** I'm using Spark 2.5.5 and spark-pac4j 2.0.0-RC2.

Is there a way to retrieve the desired parameters after filtering? Do I need to tweak my filter maybe? Or is this a bug in the Spark framework?

Any support would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my mistake. Instead of decoding the parameters from the body manually in the `decodeParams()` method, I should have used the request's `queryParams()` method to get the desired values. The following code works for me even with a filter applied:

```
post("/upload",(request, response) -> {     
    final String param1 = request.queryParams("key1");
    final String param2 = request.queryParams("key2");
    // post-process parameters
    // ...
    return "success";
});
```